# Test Samsung Smart TV App on old tv-devices (2011)

Tags: sdk, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

How can I test my app on old Samsung devices (2011)? I developed the app with Tizen and now i want to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik Tizen did not arrive in 2011, so you cannot. For example displays released by SAMSUNG for the purposes of signage switched to Tizen in 2015 iirc. Previously they ran Orsay. Not sure when SmartTVs switched.

Answer (score 0):

For Samsung 2011 (Orsay platform) you must download the SDK and it depends on your code, for example, if your application uses the Tizen API, refactor it.

You can consult the [following](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/samsung-legacy-platform) information on the Orsay platform.

If your application is not very complex, you can [migrate](https://github.com/Samsung/cordova-plugin-toast/wiki/Prepare-to-convert-for-Tizen) it to [TOAST](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/extension-libraries/toast)

Also, if you plan to send the application to the Samsung application store, you must have the Tizen application published to start the Orsay QA.